# Why is my program giving "Wrong Answer" for this program?

Tags: python

I was solving [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-quest-1) question in Hackerrank and matched the result in my IDE. 
But then the answer is not being accepted by Hackerrank.

My code is:

```
for i in range(1,int(raw_input())):
    print (str(i)*i)
```

Please help...

[Snapshot of the solution displayed by the Online judge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0USza.png)

Comment: I encourage you to contact them.

Comment: Oh wait, it says use only arithmetics. I think string repetition is not arithmetics

Comment: Confirmed, the solution using only integer arithmetics is accepted. The verifier message is misleading though.

Comment: @TamasHegedus So this means I should remove this String repetition? It made the solution quite easy...

Comment: _Note: Using anything related to strings will give a score of 0._ (...)

Comment: @Shadow_Sphynx, although you have a legitime question, most computer program challenge sites ask to not publish answers to their challenges.  It is legitime to discuss challenges faced but without providing full answer or code that might help others to pass tests there.

Comment: @Shadow_Sphynx Looks like this task is not about doing it the easy way. They want you to use *maths*

Comment: Wow! Is it possible they already clarified the question? I think it was different like 15 mins ago

Comment: @JrBenito I was unaware of that. But it would have been impossible to know my problem without sharing my code. 

I hope sharing "wrong solution" is no offence though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task says:

> Can you do it using only arithmetic operations, a single for loop and
>   print statement?
>
> Use no more than two lines. The first line (the for statement) is
>   already written for you. You have to complete the print statement.
>
> Note: Using anything related to strings will give a score of 0.

This is clear, you cannot use `str(i)`.